# Site-to-Site VPN: remote machines can't access local machines

Tags: vpn, sonicwall, site-to-site-vpn

In our office network we have a VPN setup to our datacenter. We are using a Sonicwall NAS. The VPN works fine for most cases. From our office we can connect to the servers in our DC but if I were to remote into a server in the DC and try to ping a local host then the requests time out.

We also have site-to-site tunnels between two other offices and if I remote into a machine in any of those two offices I can ping local machines.

So let's say we have our 4 networks which are as follows:

- 10.10.10.0/24 (DataCenter)
- 192.168.0.0/24 (Office 1)
- 192.168.1.0/24 (Office 2)
- 192.168.2.0/24 (Office 3)

Then the issue is that:

- DataCenter can talk to: Office 1, Office 2
- Office 1 can talk to Office 2, Office 3, DataCenter
- Office 2 can talk to Office 1, Office 3, DataCenter
- Office 3 can talk to DataCenter, Office 1, Office 2

I can't figure out why DataCenter can't talk to Office 3. As far as I can tell, all 3 tunnels are configured the same way and there is no non-standard/automatic routes, NAT rules, or firewall rules.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the DG at the DC so I can't see the table, but the routes look like this:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.1.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.10.10.1
  2     9 ms    10 ms     9 ms  192.168.1.1

Tracing route to 192.168.2.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.10.10.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  ...
  30    *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Comment: Are you trying to ping a local host from remote by IP or DNS?

Comment: I am trying to ping by IP. I cannot even ping our local gateway in Office 3 from the DataCenter while I can ping the gateways of Office 1 and Office 2 from the DataCenter.

Comment: What kind of server? Windows Server or Linux?

Comment: Run a tracert from the datacenter to office 3 and see what the results are. The traffic may be taking a path you're not expecting (and therefore not getting to office 3). If the path looks OK, then run a packet capture on both ends while you ping one from the other (and vice versa) to see if you're seeing the ICMP traffic going in both directions from both sides.

Comment: The tracert is definitely strange. Going from DC->O1 or DC->O2 it's a straight jump from gateway -> host while going from DC->O3 we see the gateway followed by lots of hops which timeout. Is it a routing issue on the gateway in the DC?

Comment: Probably. Check the routing table on the DG at the DC to make sure it's correct. Also, run a packet capture from the DC while pinging or tracing O3 and look for ICMP redirects. It may be that traffic to O3 is being redirected unintentionally.

Comment: Both our Windows Server 2008 and Ubuntu Linux boxes have the same behavior. It's not limited it ICMP traffic as RDP, HTTP, HTTPS, and SSH traffic also doesn't go through.

Comment: No, an ICMP redirect affects all traffic. It's an ICMP packet from a router telling the source host (for any and all traffic; RDP, HTTP, etc) to take another route. If there's an ICMP redirect occurring then that's definitely the issue. - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_Redirect_Message

Comment: From one of the linux boxes in the DC I did a tcpdump looking for icmp redirect packets but couldn't see any.

Comment: How does the routing table on the DG at the DC look? Can you post the output of a tracert from the DC to O2 and from the DC to O3 for comparison?

Comment: I don't have access to the DG in the DC so I can't see the routing table, but the trace routes are posted.